# Web tech-stack for interactive geo maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asp.net-web-api, maps, openstreetmap

I want to implement Web project that will primarily:

> - consist of some kind of map (google maps,open street map, etc) of my local place (city/village)
> - appear in real-time with colorful tags on map which shop is open/close
> - on clicking on tag/point will popup a message info with photo and details of shop

What alternatives/stack technology are suitable for this case(open source project)? Only *free* suggestions, without any $ plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a web framework of your choice or just javascript and [leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com) (based on openstreetmap).

Comment: Wow. Frankly, first ever hear it. Thanks!

Comment: Dude, I have < 15 reputation, otherwise I would vote :)